# Geometric series of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ z $ be a complex number. I want to find the radius of convergence of $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n} $$

My intuition is that this series converges for $ z\in D\left(0,1\right) $ (open unit disk).

Basicly, my intuition is based on the formula for real numbers $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{k}=\frac{1}{1-x} $$

Where $|x|<1 $.

Does this formula hold for complex $ |z|< 1 $? if so, how can I prove it?
That would prove that for $ |z| < 1 $ this series converge.

Now what about $ |z|=1 $ ? obviously for $ z=1 $ this series diverges, but what about $ |z|=1, z\neq1 $ ? My intuition is that the series would converge in this case, since both the imaginary part and the real part of $ z $ are smaller then $ 1 $ (also except for z=i, z=-i etc..).

How can I prove in a formal way that this series diverges for $ z=i, z=-i $ ?

Im not sure what tools from real series we can use in the complex case, so a few clarifications would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To compute the radius of convergence, the same proof as in the real case carries over: the $n^\text{th}$ partial sum is $\frac{1 - z^{n+1}}{1-z}$ for $z \neq 1$, and this converges to $\frac{1}{1-z}$ if $|z|<1$. To show that the series diverges for $z = \pm i$, you can simply compute a general formula for the sequence of partial sums---you'll see that it is periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the series converges for $|z|<1$. It diverges for all $z$ with $|z|=1$ because $|z^n|=1$ (i.e. does not converge to $0$).

EDIT:
For the sum of the geometric progression we have:
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n z^k=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}.
$$
Therefore for $|z|<1$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$
since $\lim_{n\to\infty} z^{n+1}=0$.

Comment: How can I prove that the formula I used still holds in the complex case for $z$ in the open unit disk?

Comment: I have added a proof of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Hadamard, the radius of convergence is $r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}1/\sqrt [n]{|a_n|}=1/\sqrt [n]1=1$.

In general,  you need to investigate convergence on $|z|=r $ independently.  But in this case,  when  $|z|=1$, we have that $z^n\not\to0$.  Hence the series diverges.

Comment: So for any $ r>1$, if $ |z|=r $ then we have divergence because $ z^n $ dosent converge to 0. Also, how do I justify the the formula for the geometric sum still holds for any $ z $ in the open unit disk?

Comment: For any $|z|\ge1$ it diverges.  The formula  $\sum_{n=0}^kz^n=(1-z^{k+1})/(1-z) $ is a bit of algebra which always holds true.

Comment: Take the limit as $k\to\infty $.  Then $z^{k+1}\to0$ and we are left with the formula.